# Persistent bluetooth connection - confused by lifecycle of activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-livedata, android-bluetooth, android-viewmodel

I have been working with the Android example project for Bluetooth communication (https://github.com/googlearchive/android-BluetoothChat). It provides a fairly simple chat functionality where you can connect devices and send messages back and forth. It works perfectly. In particular, when I connect to a device and then rotate my screen to landscape it stays connected.

I have been trying to modify this project by moving it from a fragment to an activity. But it's not working quite the same. In particular, whenever I rotate my screen it kills the connection. I know this is something to do with the Lifecycle of the activity, but I can't see why it would behave differently from the fragment.

My question is in two parts.

### Q1. Why does the fragment not kill the connection when I rotate the screen but the activity does?

I will try to include what I think are the relevant parts of the two projects.

**The example project using a fragment**

```
public class SampleActivityBase extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

}

public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            BluetoothChatFragment fragment = new BluetoothChatFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

}

public class BluetoothChatFragment extends Fragment {

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else if (mChatService == null) {
            setupChat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mChatService != null) {
            mChatService.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
        // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
        // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
        if (mChatService != null) {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
            if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
                // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                mChatService.start();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_chat, container, false);
    }

}
```

**My project using an activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Add toolbar
        Toolbar ActivityToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(ActivityToolbar);

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else if (mChatService == null) {
            setupChat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mChatService != null) {
            mChatService.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
        // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
        // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
        if (mChatService != null) {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
            if (mChatService.getState() == mChatService.STATE_NONE) {
                // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                mChatService.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Q2. What are the best practices for what I'm trying to achieve?

I pulled the code from the fragment to the activity because ultimately I want to have a single activity with many fragments all accessing the same Bluetooth connection. I want to have an icon in the ActionBar of the MainActivity that shows the current state of the connection. I'm assuming the best way to do this is with a ViewModel and LiveData. But I'm a little confused how it all fits together and how everything is supposed to communicate with each other. Do I create the ViewModel in the OnCreate of the activity and pass it to the instantiation of the BluetoothService class? Or do I extend the ViewModel to contain the entire BluetoothService class? Currently, the project uses a handler to pass messages from the BluetoothService class back to the fragment. Should I still use this, or would the LiveData approach be sufficient.

Sorry if my question is not clear enough. Please let me know if there is more information you need.